# Accessing GroupStyle's DataTemplate controls from code-behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an ItemsControl with a GroupStyle defined in order to group my items according to a certain rule.

I am trying to access the items within the GroupStyle's DataTemplate from my code-behind. Is such a thing possible ?

Here is the GroupStyle's definition; I would like to access either the StackPanel or the various labels within it:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Conversations}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ConversationTemplate}" Margin="15,1,15,1" x:Name="MainItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="10, 20, -250, 8">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="GroupStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Loaded="OnConversationGroupCreated" Tag="{Binding Name}">
                            <Label x:Name="VolumeLabel" Style="{DynamicResource HighlightedMetadataStyle}" Content="{Binding Name.Volume}" Panel.ZIndex="3"/>
                            <Label x:Name="ActLabel" Style="{DynamicResource HighlightedMetadataStyle}" Margin="-16,0,0,0" Content="{Binding Name.Act}" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
                            <Label x:Name="ChapterLabel" Style="{DynamicResource HighlightedMetadataStyle}" Margin="-16,0,0,0" Content="{Binding Name.Chapter}" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="#FFDDDDDD" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,8,0,0"/>
                        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="#FFEAEAEA" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,9,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the template via `MainItemsControl.GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate`
then use `VisualTreeHelper` to find the correct control inside the template